# What Git operations lock the database?

Tags: git, locking

Git has a variety of operations for reading/writing to their internal database.  I've read that write operations are atomic in Git.  However, for other operations like reads, what operations will lock the database?

Specifically, I am writing an application that will be concurrently calling "git blame" and I want to make sure this is something that I can multithread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn’t check this in the source, but from knowing git’s internal structure, I would say that everything apart from `git gc` can be multithreaded.

Git is just a bunch of object files that reference each other, but are only allowed to reference in one direction (“the past”). Apart from branch heads, the contents of a git repository can not be modified (only extended) and `git gc` is the only operation that will delete stuff from a git repository.

That is why git needs absolute minimal locking, and also why you should be fine. Note that the index is excepted from all this – that will be frequently locked, but `git blame HEAD` and every command you would run on a bare repo do not use the index.

Answer (score 1):

Minimal locking is indeed needed.

The only caveat is when running *several* [`git gc`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) concurrently, as illustrated by [commit ed7eda8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed7eda8b38ec6230abf79986668ccb6e2e2c7494) by [Kyle J. McKay (mackyle)](https://github.com/mackyle) for Git <del>1.9/2.0 (Q1 2014)</del>, actually Git 1.8.5.3, released January 15th, 2014.

Since [64a99eb4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/64a99eb4760de2ce2f0c04e146c0a55c34f50f20) (git 1.8.5), `git gc` refuses to run without the `--force` option if
another `gc` process on the same repository is already running.

> However, if the repository is shared and user `A` runs `git gc` on the repository and while that `gc` is still running user `B` runs `git gc` on the same repository the `gc` process run by user `A` will not be noticed and the `gc` run by user `B` will go ahead and run.
>
> The problem is that the `kill(pid, 0)` test fails with an `EPERM` error since user `B` is not allowed to signal processes owned by user `A` (unless user `B` is `root`).
>
> Update the test to recognize an `EPERM` error as meaning the process exists and another `gc` should not be run (unless `--force` is given).

So unless you are in that scenario, you can call you other `git` commands concurrently without any issue.